# Add a ''glossy'' material for Blender render?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm making a 3D realistic eye on Blender, I started by an already pre-made file, and it came with a transparent material/layer that works like glossynes, still it doesn't apply to the texture on the background (the pupil).
How can I make this model look better by making it reflect or 'shine'?

**This is my actual project:**

[image: screen shot of blender showing the eye model]

**Everything is fine, but I want it to look like this:**

[image: example eye]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Blender internal renderer you need to enable mirror and adjust the reflectivity, to see an actual reflection like in the image you posted you need other objects like the windows in the environment. Thats the reason why I added a color grid.

[image]

A textured face mirroring (mirror and ray-mirror in the textures Influence/Shading are not ticked)

[image]

Comment: It's not working, as you can see, it's not reflecting anything :/
https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10922647_331222347066378_5336751961493489663_n.jpg?oh=efb098ebd4fee89db2799c58bf265dd7&oe=5567FFC6&__gda__=1429783066_3d695511e073236ae875391b4cfd387e

Comment: What are your textures "Influence/Shading" settings for mirror and ray-mirror? According to your images you use only one texture material.